# Smooth Scroll Animation in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```js
// Smooth scroll for the navigation menu and links with .scrollto classes
$(document).on('click', '.nav-menu a, .scrollto', function(e) {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    if (target.length) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var scrollto = target.offset().top;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollto
      }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

      if ($(this).parents('.nav-menu, .mobile-nav').length) {
        $('.nav-menu .active, .mobile-nav .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
      }

      if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
        $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
        $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.smoothScroll {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-menu>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-menu a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #45505b;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-menu a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-menu a span {
  padding: 0 5px 0 7px;
  color: #45505b;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav-menu a {
    width: 56px;
  }
  .nav-menu a span {
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

.nav-menu a:hover,
.nav-menu .active>a,
.nav-menu li:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #0563bb;
}

.nav-menu a:hover span,
.nav-menu .active>a span,
.nav-menu li:hover>a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover,
.nav-menu li:hover>a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu a:hover span,
.nav-menu li:hover>a span {
  display: block;
}


/* Mobile Navigation */

.mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 9998;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none !important;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #45505b;
}

.mobile-nav-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-nav-active #header {
  left: 0;
}

.mobile-nav-active .mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #0563bb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#hero"><i class="bx bx-home"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#about"><i class="bx bx-user"></i> <span>About Me</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#resume"><i class="bx bx-file"></i> <span>Resume</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#services"><i class="bx bx-server"></i> <span>Skills</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#project"><i class="bx bx-collection"></i> <span>Projects</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#References"><i class="bx bx-message"></i> <span>References</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="bx bx-envelope"></i> <span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Basically, I have added another scroll button in the website, and I created a different CSS class called `.smoothScroll` which can be seen in the above code CSS. I want to incorporate/add this particular class to the existing JS code. Basically, see how the JS code handles the smooth scroll with different class such as `.nav-menu a`? I want to add `.smoothScroll` in there too so the **same** smooth scrolling effect is on `.smoothScroll` too. Wherever I use this class, I would like smoothscroll on it.

Please do not change the existing JS code or remove any classes from it, I just want to be able to add `.smoothScroll` class in there so it has the scrolling effect. How can I add it in there? I tried adding it but it did not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard off CSS property scroll behavior? No need to do that with js
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Comment: Yes I am aware, however, I would prefer the JS one